# Is there a more efficient way to script this API call using zenpy?

Tags: python-3.x, zendesk, zendesk-api

I have written a small script to query the Zendesk API for ticket comments based on a provided list of ticket ids.

I only have a little experience using this module and want to be sure my loop method is calling the API the least number of times.  I'm looking for maximum performance in general, and I have hunch that my iterative loop is not the best way to do this.

I've reviewed the zenpy docs as well as Zendesk API guidelines and have implemented the proactive rate limiting within zenpy to avoid hitting the rate limit.  I also saw sideloading as a way to prevent excessive API calls but cannot clearly discern how to implement that in my code :(

```py
import zenpy, datetime, zdcreds

zenpy_client = zenpy.Zenpy(proactive_ratelimit=700, **zdcreds.creds)

#later this will pull from a csv or excel range
ticket_list = [799380, 805404] 

pre_df = {'ticket_id':[], 'comment_text':[], 'author_id':[]}

for t in ticket_list:
    for comment in zenpy_client.tickets.comments(ticket=t):
        pre_df['ticket_id'].append(t)
        pre_df['comment_text'].append(comment.body)
        pre_df['author_id'].append(comment.author)

#will output data to file
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used zenpy before but I can share from my experience that when calling API's or scraping websites a first good to go approach is adding a sleep time between each call. So to give an example with your code it can be something like this:

```
import zenpy, datetime, zdcreds, time, random

zenpy_client = zenpy.Zenpy(proactive_ratelimit=700, **zdcreds.creds)

#later this will pull from a csv or excel range
ticket_list = [799380, 805404] 

pre_df = {'ticket_id':[], 'comment_text':[], 'author_id':[]}

for t in ticket_list:
    for comment in zenpy_client.tickets.comments(ticket=t):
        pre_df['ticket_id'].append(t)
        pre_df['comment_text'].append(comment.body)
        pre_df['author_id'].append(comment.author)
        time.sleep(random.randint(2,5))


#will output data to file
```

So this will add a random sleep time between 2-5 seconds to your code. You can test some numbers and see which one does a better job to avoid rate limits. You can also keep the sleep time constant but some APIs can catch that I think. This will most probably avoid excessive calls. Your code will take longer to run but not hit the rate limit.